# Grafana dashboards combine two SQL queries

Tags: postgresql, grafana, timescaledb

I have one Grafana dashboard with 2 queries that `sum` certain data from a postgres (timescale) db. Both queries are nearly identical, is it possible to combine these two queries into one as well as combining the sums?

Query one:

```
SELECT
    $__timeGroup(time, '1m'),
    SUM(value*2.119) as "Trane VAVs"
FROM 
    slipstream_volttron
WHERE
    $__timeFilter("time") AND
    (metric ~ 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/.*/Discharge Air Flow$')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Query two:

```
SELECT
    $__timeGroup(time, '1m'),
    SUM(value) as "JCI VAVs"
FROM 
    slipstream_volttron
WHERE
    $__timeFilter("time") AND
    (metric ~ 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/.*/SA-F$')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

For example this screenshot is what it looks like hoping to combine these queries and `SUMS` where there would be only 1 line not two. One line of all of the data summed up.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Ryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72263649/13439686) that uses a query to combine the two results, I want to share a way to accomplish your goal with Grafana.

You can use a [Transformation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transform-data/about-transformation/).
Go to the tab `Transform`, select `Add field from calculation`, and chose `Mode`: `Binary operation`. Then you can select your two query results, choose `+` as operator, give an alias and choose to hide the inital fields if you want.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished in Postgres with an aggregate `FILTER()`. Something like:

```sql
SELECT
    $__timeGroup(time, '1m'),
    SUM(value*2.119) FILTER(WHERE metric ~ 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/.*/Discharge Air Flow$') as "Trane VAVs",
    SUM(value) FILTER(WHERE metric ~ 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/.*/SA-F$') as "JCI VAVs"
FROM 
    slipstream_volttron
WHERE
    $__timeFilter("time")
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

That said, without knowing the schema of `slipstream_volttron` (column types, indexes, etc.) there might be some additional efficiencies that would improve the query speed, etc. `FILTER()` is applied to the all rows that match the query predicates so if you have lots of raw data, you would try to add a `WHERE` clause on the main query that would use indexes to return fewer rows (in addition to the `time` column that you're filtering on)

Also, depending on what type of your `metric` column is, the cardinality, and how it's indexed, you could probably get better query performance with a few more tweaks. Regex is a powerful tool but not always the most efficient during real-time aggregation.